Görtz-Wedhorn corollary 5.33 : $\operatorname{codim}_X V(f_1, \dotsc, f_r) \leq r$ if $X$ is a $k$-scheme of finite type
I don't understand how to conclude the proof of the corollary 5.33 of Görtz-Wedhorn's "AG1 : Schemes". Here is the statement with the previous theorem ($k$ is any field) :


Theorem 5.32. Let $X$ be an integral $k$-scheme of finite type and let $f \in \Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X)$ be a non-unit, and different from $0$. Then $V(f)$ is equi-codimensional of codimension $1$ in $X$.



Corollary 5.33. Let $X$ be a $k$-scheme of finite type and let $f_1, \dotsc, f_r \in \Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X)$ with $V(f_1, \dotsc, f_r) \neq \emptyset$. Then $\operatorname{codim}_X V(f_1, \dotsc, f_r) \leq r$.


For the proof, the authors argue by induction on $r$.

Proof : Assume the result true for $V(f_1, \dotsc, f_{r-1})$ and let $Z$ be an irreducible component of the latter scheme. Then $f_r$, restricted to $Z$, either vanished identically, in which case $Z$ is contained in $V(f_1, \dotsc, f_r)$, or it does not vanish identically, and we can apply Theorem 5.32.

From what I understand, if we write $f_r \vert_Z$ for the image of $f_r$ under the morphism $\Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X) \to \Gamma(Z,\mathcal O_Z)$ where $Z$ is equipped with its reduced scheme structure (so it’s an integral $k$-scheme of finite type), we have either $V_Z(f_r\vert_Z) = Z$ or $\operatorname{codim}_Z V_Z(f_r\vert_Z) \leq 1$ thanks to Theorem 5.32. I do not understand how to deduce the result of the statement from this? We have (using the definition of codimension with the infinimum of the dimensions of local rings)
$$\operatorname{codim}_X V(f_1, \dotsc, f_r) = \inf_Z~ \operatorname{codim}_X V_Z(f_r \vert_Z) ~~(*)$$
where $Z$ runs through the irreducible components of $V(f_1, \dotsc, f_{r-1})$ and
$$\operatorname{codim}_Z V_Z(f_r\vert_Z) = \dim Z - \dim V_Z(f_r\vert_Z)$$
because $Z$ is integral and of finite type over $k$. Thus
$$\operatorname{codim}_X V_Z(f_r\vert_Z) \leq \dim X - \dim V_Z(f_r\vert_Z) = \dim X - \dim Z + 1$$
and the equality $(*)$ implies $\operatorname{codim}_X V(f_1, \dotsc, f_r) \leq \dim X - \dim V(f_1, \dotsc, f_{r-1}) +1$. But since X is not irreducible, we don’t usually have $\dim X - \dim V(f_1, \dotsc, f_r) = \operatorname{codim}_X V(f_1, \dotsc, f_{r-1})$ and I'm stuck... I think I’m missing a much simpler argument. Do you have any leads? Thank you.

Morally, the result can be achieved by applying their argument to the irreducible components of $X$. After all you are only interested in a worst-case bound. Consider, for example, the case $r=1$ for not necessarily irreducible $X$. Then on each irreducible component $X_i$ of $X$ $f = f_1$ cuts out one of the following:

All of $X_i$ (if $f = 0$ or more generally $f$ vanishes everywhere - $X$ might be non-reduced). Then we get codimension $0 \leq 1$.
$\emptyset$ (if $f$ is a unit). Then codimension is not a thing by the definition used in the book (by the hypothesis of the corollary, this cannot happen on each $X_i$).
A bunch of irreducible codimension 1 subschemes $Y_1, \dots, Y_N$ in $X_i$.

Regarding case 3: If $Y_j$ is of codimension $\leq 1$ in $X$, then we are happy. If not, then there must be a strict inclusion of irreducible subsets
\begin{equation}
Y_j \subsetneq Y \subsetneq X_{i'},
\end{equation}
which must necessarily take place in a different irreducible component of $X$ (i.e. $i' \neq i$). But this implies that $Y_j$ is not an irreducible component of $V(f) \subseteq X$, because by Theorem 5.32. it would necessarily have to be of codimension 1 in $X_{i'}$. Thus $Y_j$ is irrelevant for the computation of the codimension of $V(f)$ in $X$.
As you observed, the rest is now induction. For the step $(r-1) \to r$ we have:
The scheme $V(f_1, \dots, f_{r-1})$ is the union of several irreducible components ($Z$ in the notation of the book). First of all I claim that each such $Z$ has codimension at most $r-1$ in $X$. If not, then there is a strict chain of irreducible closed subsets
\begin{equation}
Z = Z_r \subsetneq Z_{r-1} \subsetneq \dots \subsetneq Z_0 = X_i
\end{equation}
ending in some irreducible component $X_i$ of $X$. This cannot happen because we have only used $r-1$ functions to cut out $Z$ on $X_i$, and we need at least one for each step $Z_{j+1} \subsetneq Z_{j}$ (short remark: One can also just prove this for the case $r=1$ (either by hand as above or by invoking Krull's Principal Ideal Theorem) and make it part of the induction hypothesis).
Now we intersect each such component $Z$ with $V(f_r)$, and this gives a collection of irreducible schemes all of codimension at most 1 in $Z$ (by the case $r=1$). Now for each of these new irreducible schemes, by 5.30.1) you get codimension at most $r$ in $X$.
I hope this helped. Best,
Clemens

Thank you for your answer. I started thinking about it but I’m a little short on time. I’ll come back to that later in the day. I think there is a small typo in the message: you must replace "at most" by "at least" since we work with codimensions (it does not change the background of your message)!

I think the phrase "at most" is correct (exactly because we are talking about codimension), since we are measuring "dimensional distance" starting from $X$, and we move away by "at most" $r$ steps (we either make a real step away or we make a step on the spot that we are on).

By definition, if $Y$ is a closed subset of $X$, we have $\operatorname{codim}_X Y = \inf_Z \operatorname{codim}_X Z$ where $Z$ are the irreducible components of $Y$. It is possible that $\operatorname{codim}X V(f_1, \dotsc, f{r-1}) \leq r-1$ while one of the irreducible components of this closed set has codimension $\geq r$, that's why I think we have to say "at least".

And I'm not sure about "Since $X_i$ is an irreducible component in $X$, each $Y_j$ is also codimension 1 in X". Nevertheless, this is true if $X_i$ is an irreducible component of $X$ such that $\dim Z = \dim X$.

You raise some good points, and I'll try to address them later today.

I have expanded my answer to address your points. I hope this makes it clearar. Feel free to raise any further issues.
